# Print out centroid coordinates of a polygon in layout text box

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, qgsexpression

I wanted to put the coordinates of the centre of a polygon in a text box in the print composer. When I run the expression in the labelling panel on the canvas it works, like below
[image]

However, when I run the same expression in a text box in print composer, I get an error.
[image]

Is there something that is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression pre validation sometimes is not working properly in the print composer even if the expression is valid and would work.

Your first expression is evaluated on the layer so get_feature_by_id have no problem to verify the formula result and let you click ok button.

To make it work you have to add the expression without the expression dialogu box. In the text field add `[% your expression %]`. No validation would be done and it should work.

If not then may be use the layer id instead of layer name.